# Azure PaaS Redis System.NullReferenceException at Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnectionAsync

Tags: azure, paas, redis

We are encountering the following error frequently in our application.

**Problem Id:**

```
System.NullReferenceException at Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnectionAsync+<EvalAsync>d__22.MoveNext
```

**Message:** Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**Exception type:** System.NullReferenceException

**Failed method:**

```
Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnectionAsync+<EvalAsync>d__22.MoveNext
```

**Call Stack:**

```
System.NullReferenceException:
   at System.Object.GetType (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnectionAsync+<EvalAsync>d__22.MoveNext (Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisSessionStateProviderAsync+<SetAndReleaseItemExclusiveAsync>d__20.MoveNext (Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModuleAsync+<ReleaseStateAsyncImpl>d__80.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask (Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication+AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
```

The application is deployed on Sitecore Managed Cloud Service Azure PaaS and uses Redis app service.

`Sitecore Version: 10.2`

`StackExchange.Redis DLL version:` [image]

I have followed the below links as well:

[Sitecore PAAS Redis Exception](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17809/sitecore-paas-redis-exception)

[Azure Web App Redis timeout exceptions when under load](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5965/azure-web-app-redis-timeout-exceptions-when-under-load)

Any help, please?

Comment: You need to verify redis server is running properly and please check if redis configuration is correct.

Comment: Redis server is running properly and configuration is as pe https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0464570

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After investigation and Google, we have found that our `web.config` contains the following settings:

[image]

Based on this information we can confirm that the reported behavior is a registered bug.

To track the future status of this bug report, please use **reference number 505522**.

To workaround this issue, we consider setting `aspnet:AllowConcurrentRequestsPerSession to false`.

**Please note:** that it is also not recommended to enable `aspnet:AllowConcurrentRequestsPerSession` according to Sitecore doc as it might cause unexpected behavior such as data loss. For more information please refer to this documentation: [Walkthrough: Configuring a private session state database using the Redis provider](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/walkthrough--configuring-a-private-session-state-database-using-the-redis-provider.html)

However, if you wish to keep `aspnet:AllowConcurrentRequestsPerSession enable`, you could consider an `upgrade to XP 10.3` as this bug is fully resolved in that version.

For more details see the blog post: [Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnectionAsync](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2023/04/sitecore-sessionprovider-redis-stackexchange-clientconnectionasync.html)